# Html load detection with GeckoFx

Tags: c#, geckofx

I have a bot that navigate on a site, that site have a main div and if the bot click in one link from menu a jquery script will make the load of source into that main div, so my question is how can i detect if the request as made or if i got a response.
I can't compare the html because some times he request the same page 2 or 3 times so the html will be the same.
I already tried documentcompleted but doesn't work with jquery loads.